# Delete rows before doing any transformation in datastage designer?

Tags: designer, delete-row, datastage

I want to delete some rows before doing any processing. But I don't know how to do it in datastage designer? Is there any stage that holds sql requests??

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the job you will do to do the "processing" you can do one job that has 2 stages: a row_generator and a database link (depending on you db).
Configure the row generator to generate 1 row only. On the db stage you can do whatever delete ou want. This will be your job that deletes the rows you want.
After that, do a sequence job and add the job you've done to delete rows and link it to whatever jobs you want to run next - don't forget to configure the triggers on the these links.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done via writing a SQL in the BEFORE SQL part of the source database connector stage.
So whenever your job runs first that delete query would be executed and other things later.

Thankyou